# Hand interaction working in Editor but not on Hololens 2

Tags: hololens, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

I am currently developing my first hololens 2 application. In it, I create an interactable with box collider at runtime. In the Unity editor I can grab and move it around, but on Hololens, if I try to grab it, nothing happens. Does anyone have any leads on why this could be?

EDIT: The Example App is installed and Hand Tracking works as intended. The issue seems to not be caused by faulty sensors

Properties (at runtime, after instantiating):
[image]

[image]

Comment: Which generation of HoloLens are you using? HoloLens (1st gen) or HoloLens2? HoloLens (1st gen) doesn't support direct manipulation with hands. It is a newest feature of HoloLens2. So, we recommend that you use `Gaze and commit` instead of it, more information please see:[Introducing instinctual interactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/design/interaction-fundamentals)

Comment: I am building for Hololens 2. Are there any troubleshooting steps I can try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is recommended to double-check the Unity Project Setting to troubleshoot, please follow this doc to [declare the appropriate capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/configure-unity-project#updating-the-manifest). And then you need to configure the XR Plugin. For XR SDK, please follow this link: [Getting started with MRTK and XR SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/configuration/getting-started-with-mrtk-and-xrsdk), for Legacy XR, have a look at [For Legacy XR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/configure-unity-project#for-legacy-xr).

After this, please try deploying the scene Assets/MRTK/Examples/Demos/HandTracking/Scenes/HandInteractionExamples.unity to your device.  Do you see the same behavior? This will help narrow down if it's an issue with your configuration or an issue with your scene.

Besides, we always recommend the latest Unity LTS (Long Term Support) stream as the best version to develop MR app, and the current recommendation is to use Unity 2019.4: https://unity3d.com/unity/qa/lts-releases

Comment: Ich checked everything and your links helped me. It works now. Thank you so much